# Error 6: Overflow (failed to read from another cells, 0/0)

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, overflow, divide-by-zero

I have a problem, I checked a lot of forums, but it doesn't help. I tried few solutions (MsgBox Cells(i,14), but it seems like it doesn't read from cells in the same sheet, because there is 0/0. Here is part of my code:

```
Option Explicit

Type Particle 
    s(3) As Double 
    n(3) As Double 
    d As Double 
    dn As Double 
    e(3) As Double 
    o(3) As Double 
End Type

Sub ReadingData()

    'SPREMENLJIVKE
    Dim p As Particle
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim st As Integer


    st = 3
    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(st, 14))

            Cells(st, 14) = p.s(1)
            Cells(st, 24) = p.dn

    st = st + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Sub NormalizacijaVektorja()

Dim p As Particle
Dim i As Integer



i = 3



Call ReadingData


While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 20))

        p.e(1) = p.s(1) / p.dn
        Cells(i, 26) = p.e(1)


i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: try sheet1.cells or whatever your worksheet is called rather than just cells

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer! I tried ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(st, 14) = p.s(1), but it gives em the same error, also I tried Worksheets("Modul").Cells(st, 24) = p.dn, also the same error. I added a watch to p.dn, and it gives me "out of the context" value....I am really confused right now....btw. I have this in modules, not on specific sheet, is there a catch here? Thank you